# How to stream media from one android device to another?

Tags: android, video-streaming, streaming

I need to implement an app that sends streaming media (image, audio or video) from one android device to another. I've analyzed many examples of how to receive the stream on android, but almost nothing to stream. I have tried to make some examples work using GStreamer + NDK, but to no avail as well.
Does anyone know of another form or library that assists with it with android?

Comment: You can use WebRTC, but the learning curve is rather steep.

Comment: Hmm ... I'll take a look at this WebRTC to see how it works. Thank you.